# In a ES6 class method, how to ensure "this" always point to the class itself, not child class?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
class Parent {
    func1() {
        console.log("I am func1, in class Parent");
    }

    func2() {
        this.func1();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    func1() {
        console.log("I am func1, in class Child");
    }
}

let a = new Child();
a.func2();
```

Because "this" point to Child when call a.func2(), so it will output "I am func1, in class Child".

But now I want Parent.func2() always call Parent.func1() in any case, even if "this" is binded with Child, how can I do that?

I tried

```
func2() {
    super.func1();
}
```

Obviously it cannot work when Parent call func2():

```
let b = new Parent();
b.func2(); //not work
```

I want something like this:

```
class Parent {
    func1() {
        console.log("I am func1, in class Parent");
    }

    func2() {
        Parent.func1(); //always access Parent.func1() even if func1() is overrode. 
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You have overridden `func1` in the child. You should look at inheritance first.

Comment: I don't understand, what you want to achieve. With this code: `let a = new Child();
a.func2();

let b = new Parent();
b.func2(); ` what is your expected output?

Answer (score 4):

There is no special syntax for that, you will need to explicitly refer to the method that you want to call exactly:

```
class Parent {
    func1() {
        console.log("I am func1, in class Parent");
    }

    func2() {
        Parent.prototype.func1.call(this);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. This works for me. Or did you intend anything else?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(t) {
    this.t = t
    console.log('Parent constructor', t)
  }
  func1() {
    console.log("I am func1, in class Parent", this.t);
  }

  func2() {
    this.func1();
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(t) {
    // super() in constructor calls parent constructor
    super(t);
    console.log('Child constructor', t)
  }
  func1() {
    console.log("I am func1, in class Child", this.t);
  }

  func2() {
    // super refers to the parent class and thus
    // super.func1() calls the func1 of Parent class
    // not Child class
    super.func1();
  }
}

let a = new Child('A');
a.func2();

let b = new Parent('B');
b.func2();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   class Parent {
  func1() {
   console.log("I am func1, in class Parent");
  }

  func2() {
   this.func1();
  }
 }

class Child extends Parent {
 static func1() {
  console.log("I am func1, in class Child");
 }
}

let a = new Child();
a.func1();
a.func2();
Child.func1(); //Will call child's own static method,instead of parent
```

I use static method in child class, this can be option.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use fat arrow syntax while declaring a function, the benefit of that is when you use **this** inside a function it will always point to the class instance. So you can call it directly like below.

```
class Parent {
    func1= () => {
        console.log("I am func1");
    }

    func2 = () => {
        this.func1();
    }
}
```